# is there a function like sample_gnm( )from igraph for python?

Tags: python, r, igraph

I want to generate GN benchmark to test my community detection algorithm. I found this function in igraph `sample_gnm()`. 
However, I cannot find this function `igraph`  for python .

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is the `Erdos_Renyi` method. Specify the `m` parameter and omit `p`.

https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.GraphBase.html#Erdos_Renyi

Answer (score -1):

The [python-igraph API](https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/igraph.Graph.html) shows you all the functions that python-igraph can provide. While you can take a look at them I think your answer would be "No".